# With CSS and HTML5, when should I use static, absolute, fixed, or relative positioning?

Tags: css, html

I am trying to establish a layout for my web page. I am focusing on a navigation bar with 4 inline links on the top that stays put  and a basic text header for now that will move up as yu scroll down. I have this so far for the CSS:

```
header {
 width: 75%;
 height: 150px;
 background-color: red;
}

nav {
 background-color: blue
 width: 100%;
 height: 75px
 z-index: 2;
 }

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>NYC Autumn - Mark's CSS Switcheroo</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet2.css">

</head>

<body>
<nav>
<ul>
 <li>Picture Library</li>
 <li>Blog</li>
 <li>Site Seeing</li>
 <li>About Us</li>
</ul>
</nav>

<header>
<h1>
 New York in the Fall
</h1>
</header>
```

That is the beginning of my HTML.

Comment: Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 1):

There is no exact answer for your question. You don't provide your HTML layout nor do we know what design you are trying to accomplish.

But here is a guide:

static = Normal positioning where things stay in their normal flow of the page.

absolute = you position it top/bottom, right/left on the page with a width and height normally. And it will position relative to overall page or the closest "position: relative" parent.

fixed = similar to absolute, except that it is fixed relative to the overall window and does not move when scrolled

relative = similar to static, but it creates its own positioning context... meaning anything "position: absolute" inside of it will be relative to it. Relative can also be moved top/bottom, left/right relative to where it would normally appear on the page

Comment: Well, first of all you need to have a body tag. But it's still ambiguous what ou want because you don't say what you expect to happen. I am guessing you want to leave it the default (static), but it's not clear since we don't know your intended appearance and behavior.

Comment: I have the body tag in there. Just made a mistake with leaving it out here. Look on top: nav bar should stay on top and let the header and content scroll up underneath it.

Comment: Then your nav should be position fixed. And the rest you should leave position static. You might also want to set a padding-top on your body (or other element containing your content) equal to the height of your nav bar. This will assure that your nav bar doesn't cover your header.

Comment: That worked like a charm. I will keep practicing with padding, margins, and content.